# retrieving data from mysql DB to a drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, dropdown

This is my code but I don't seem to get anything in the dropdown list. Is there something else I'm supposed to do besides this? Or is there something wrong with my code?

```
<div class="span10 offset1">
                <div class="row">
                        <h3> Add catagory</h3>
                    </div>
                      <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-success" >';

                        <?php
                   include('database.php');

        $query = "SELECT cat_name  FROM  catagory";
$result = mysql_query ($query);
echo "<select name='dropdown' value=''><option>Dropdown</option>";
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<option value=' " . $row['cat_name'] . " '>" . $row['cat_name'] . " </option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're referencing `$row` but assigning the result to `$r`. Just change the variable:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value=' " . $r['cat_name'] . " '>" . $r['cat_name'] . " </option>";
}
```

Comment: Eh, guess I'll just have to speed up my typing skills, then!

Answer (score 1):

Your variables names look wrong

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<option value=' " . $row['cat_name'] . " '>" . $row['cat_name'] . " </option>";
}
```

You loop through the results using `$r` but use `$row[]` within the loop. It should probably read

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<option value=' " . $row['cat_name'] . " '>" . $row['cat_name'] . " </option>";
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you're connected to the MySQL server, and that you've selected the correct database to run your queries against by using `mysql_select_db($database_name)`